# Model mocks automatically have access to all existing methods of the model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Do Model mocks automatically have access to all existing methods of the model in rspec? I guess not just to confirm. Thanks.

Comment: That sound suspiciously like CS169.1x question 3.8.

Comment: It *is* part of a CS169.1x multiple choice question ... as is this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13116367/mocks-can-be-created-with-default-attribute-values however this latter is asking in a more intelligent general way that makes it look less obviously like a CS169.1x question, and indicates deeper thought on the part of the poster - might be good to have the EdX guys link their profiles to SO and CareerCup, XORswap etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you suspect, they don't. This is one of the differences between using mock/stubs and factories as testing objects:

- mocks/stubs: you predefine some behavior for an object you need for a test, but you are not testing it, so it responds with some predefined response.
- factories: you use them to generate actual objects with all their behavior, so averything can be included in the test. You tipically use factories when the factored object is the subject of the test.