# Mocks can be created with default attribute values

Tags: rspec

can mocks be created with default attribute values? I am not certain what this question really mean. Two possibilities:

1. if an object `t=Movie.find(10)`, and then if I say `m=mock(t)`, does m automatically inherit all the attribute values of t?
2. is there a way to create a mock object with default attributes such that we can clone it everytime when we use it without going thru series stubs to `"initialize"` those attributes?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to 1) It does not have a sense. If inside the test you have an access to the real object through `Movie.find(10)` you don't have to use mocks. Assuming that you're using `rspec_mocks` and you're going to write an assertion that particular method was called, you could simply write:

```
t = Movie.find(10)
t.should_receive(:foo)
```

Also check this out: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-11/docs/mocks/mock-model
and this https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-11/docs/mocks/stub-model

Very useful helpers for mocking AR/Mongoid and other models in specs.

Along with `factory_girl` you could set an attributes on this mocks, for example `movie = mock_model(Movie, FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:move))`